# How to see exact resized image is put into Vision framework?

Tags: swift, computer-vision, coreml

I only found a way to see the initial image (non-resized one) and then this image got cropped somewhere inside Vision to match input resolution for my .mlmodel. How can I see that cropped version (I capture these images from my camera)?

I use this this crop option: VNImageCropAndScaleOptionCenterCrop = 0 (I believe it doesn't matter though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a model that doesn't do anything with the image, and then look at the output image that is generated by Vision.